# getting 2-5 consecutive word phrases from a string I got 2 to work but having trouble doing 3

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator

```
vector <string> oneWordPhrase;
vector <string> twoWordPhrase;
vector <string> threeWordPhrase;

vector<string>::iterator it1;
vector<string>::iterator it2;

string str="hello my is bob oh hey jay oh";

string split = str;
string word;
stringstream stream(split);
while( getline(stream, word, ' ') )
{
  oneWordPhrase.push_back(word);
}//used to split sentence into words

for(it1=oneWordPhrase.begin(); it1!=oneWordPhrase.end(); it1++)
{
    if(it1+1 == oneWordPhrase.end())
        break;
    twoWordPhrase.push_back(*it1 + ' ' + *(it1+1));
}//getting two word phrases

cout<<"two word---------------\n";
for(int i=0; i<twoWordPhrase.size(); i++)
    cout<<twoWordPhrase[i]<<endl;

for(it1=twoWordPhrase.begin(); it1!=twoWordPhrase.end(); it1++)
{
    it2=oneWordPhrase.begin()+2;
    threeWordPhrase.push_back(*it1 + ' ' + *it2);
    ++it2;  /* was hoping that I can get each word after "is" but it 
             didn't allow me. the problem is here */
}//getting three word phrases
cout<<"three word---------------\n";

for(int i=0; i<twoWordPhrase.size(); i++)
    cout<<threeWordPhrase[i]<<endl;
```

I got my twoPhrase to print properly which is

hello my

my is

is bob

bob oh

oh hey

hey jay

jay oh

However, my threeWordPhrase prints out

hello my is

my is is

is bob is

bob oh is

oh hey is

hey jay is

jay oh is

For threeWordPhrases Im hoping to print "hello my is" "my is bob" "is bob oh" " bob oh hey" all the way to  "hey jay oh".

I pointed my it2 at myWordPhrase.begin()+2 and hoped that it would increment by 1 like it would in an array but it didn't.

I have comment the section of code that is giving me problem

I'm pretty sure if I can figure out 3 word phrase  I can do 4 and 5 word phrases so any help with the 3 words would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you need 2 to 5 word phrases, think of a general strategy that works for k-word phrases, and run that several times for different k. Presumably a solution along those lines is what whoever posed the problem is looking for...

Answer (score 0):

When you do `*it2 = oneWordPhrase.begin() + 2`  it always gives you the 3rd member in the oneWordPhrase vector. You can use a counter instead of iterator because you need to iterate over both vectors:

```
vector <string> oneWordPhrase;
vector <string> twoWordPhrase;
vector <string> threeWordPhrase;

vector<string>::iterator it1;
vector<string>::iterator it2;

string str="hello my is bob oh hey jay oh";

string split = str;
string word;
stringstream stream(split);
while( getline(stream, word, ' ') )
{
  oneWordPhrase.push_back(word);
}//used to split sentence into words

for(it1=oneWordPhrase.begin(); it1!=oneWordPhrase.end(); it1++)
{
    if(it1+1 == oneWordPhrase.end())
        break;
    twoWordPhrase.push_back(*it1 + ' ' + *(it1+1));
}//getting two word phrases

cout<<"two word---------------\n";
for(int i=0; i<twoWordPhrase.size(); i++)
    cout<<twoWordPhrase[i]<<endl;

for(int i=0; i!=twoWordPhrase.size() - 2; i++)
{
    threeWordPhrase.push_back( twoWordPhrase[i] + ' ' + oneWordPhrase[i + 2] );
      /* was hoping that I can get each word after "is" but it 
             didn't allow me. the problem is here */
}//getting three word phrases
cout<<"three word---------------\n";

for(int i=0; i<twoWordPhrase.size() - 2; i++)
    cout<<threeWordPhrase[i]<<endl;
```

Comment: that seemed to work although it is giving me an extra line of nothing. I was hoping to use an iterator to know when to break out of the loop as i did for my oneWordPhrase. none the less, thanks for your contribution